# Не создаётся запись в бд, но и ошибок никаких нет

Tags: php, html, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

не могу разобраться почему не отправляется запись в бд, хотя ошибки никакие не высвечиваются.

publish.php

```
include 'connect.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$categori = $_POST['catigoria'];
$file = $_POST['file'];
$img = $_POST['img'];
$mintext = $_POST['mintext'];
$maxtext = $_POST['maxtext'];

$connection -> query ("INSERT INTO `zapisi` (`id(n)`,`name`, `date`, `time`, `categoria`, `img`, `mintext`, `maxtext`,`file`) VALUES ('1', '$name', '$date', '$time', '$categori', '$img', '$mintext', '$maxtext' ,'$file')");
```

zapisi.php

```
<?php 
if(in_array('обосрись billy 12398',$_COOKIE)){  
    echo "";
} else {
    header('location: http://itog-progect/aut.php');
}

include 'connect.php';

if ($connection == true) {
    $t = "создать";
}else{
    $t = "нифига не подключилось";
}
?>

...

<form action="publish.php" method="post">
    <label for=""><p>название</p><input name="name" type="text"></label>
    <label for=""><p>дата</p><input name="date" type="text"></label>
    <label for=""><p>время</p><input name="time" type="text"></label>
    <label for=""><p>категория</p><input name="catigoria" type="text"></label>
    <label for=""><p>файл</p><input name="file" type="text"></label>
    <label for=""><p>картинка</p><input name="img" type="file"></label>
    <label for=""><p>кратк содержание</p><input name="mintext" type="text"></label>
    <label><p>весь текст</p><textarea name="maxtext"></textarea></label>
    <button><?php echo $t; ?></button>
</form>

...
```

Comment: А вы ошибки от БД пытаетесь обрабатывать и собственно показывать, если они есть ? (возможно надо смотреть чем закончился запрос и если false, то использовать функции вроде errorInfo()). А еще вы уверены, что запрос insert надо выполнять через query (который возможно используется когда ожидаются строки резульата), а не например через exec (зависит от того чем вы подключетесь)

Comment: Ну очень вероятно что там может быть масса оишбок, потому что вы подставляете значения прямо в текст, а не пользуетесь подготовленными запросами https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php